# Build Failure GeoNetwork opensource

Tags: maven, build, open-source, geonetwork

I try build GeoNetwork opensource, but I have the following problem when I run "mvn clean install -DskipTests":

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option         
MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.5.2
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-20-generic", arch: "amd64", family: 
"unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective 
model for org.geonetwork-opensource:wfsfeature-harvester:jar:3.4.5- 
SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ 
org.geonetwork-opensource:wfsfeature-harvester:[unknown-version], 
/home/barbara/core-geonetwork/workers/wfsfeature-harvester/pom.xml, 
line 75, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they 
threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer 
support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GeoNetwork opensource
[INFO] common utils
[INFO] Caching xslt module
[INFO] ArcSDE module (dummy-api)
[INFO] GeoNetwork domain
[INFO] Oaipmh modules
[INFO] GeoNetwork Events
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugins
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugins core
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for ISO19139/119 standards
[INFO] GeoNetwork index using Elasticsearch
[INFO] GeoNetwork index Elasticsearch client
[INFO] GeoNetwork core
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for Dublin Core records retrieved by CSW
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for Dublin Core standard
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for ISO19110 standard
[INFO] GeoNetwork CSW server
[INFO] GeoNetwork harvesters
[INFO] GeoNetwork health monitor
[INFO] GeoNetwork services
[INFO] Geonetwork Web Resources 4 Java
[INFO] GeoNetwork INSPIRE Atom
[INFO] GeoNetwork dashboard app based on Kibana
[INFO] messaging
[INFO] workers
[INFO] WFS features harvester
[INFO] Tests for schema plugins
[INFO] GeoNetwork user interface module
[INFO] JS API and Service documentation
[INFO] GeoNetwork Web module
[INFO] GeoNetwork E2E Javascript Tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GeoNetwork opensource 3.4.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from oss.sonatype.org-github-releases:    
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github- 
releases/org/zeroturnaround/jrebel-maven-plugin/1.1.5/jrebel-maven- 
plugin-1.1.5.pom
[INFO] Downloading from sonatype-public-repository: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/zeroturnaround/jrebel- 
maven-plugin/1.1.5/jrebel-maven-plugin-1.1.5.pom
[INFO] Downloading from central: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/jrebel-maven- 
plugin/1.1.5/jrebel-maven-plugin-1.1.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] GeoNetwork opensource .............................. FAILURE [  0.893 s]
[INFO] common utils ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Caching xslt module ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ArcSDE module (dummy-api) .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork domain .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Oaipmh modules ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork Events .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugins .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugins core ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for ISO19139/119 standards  SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork index using Elasticsearch ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork index Elasticsearch client .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork core .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for Dublin Core records retrieved by 
CSW SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for Dublin Core standard .. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork schema plugin for ISO19110 standard ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork CSW server .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork harvesters .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork health monitor .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork services ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Geonetwork Web Resources 4 Java .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork INSPIRE Atom ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork dashboard app based on Kibana ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] messaging .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] workers ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WFS features harvester ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Tests for schema plugins ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork user interface module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JS API and Service documentation ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork Web module .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork E2E Javascript Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.150 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-19T12:38:35+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/284M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.5 or one of 
its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact 
descriptor for org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.5: Could 
not transfer artifact org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:pom:1.1.5 
from/to oss.sonatype.org-github-releases 
(https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors 
parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I've installed Java 8
I try both from eclipse and from the command line, but it does not work.
I also tried to do mvn clear install, but nothing.

I followed this link:
https://travis-ci.org/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/builds/467950176

Some idea?

Maven - settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!--
 | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 |
 |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,
 |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
 |
 |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
 |                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
 |                 installation). It's normally provided in
 |                 ${maven.conf}/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
 |
 | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at
 | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default
 | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
 |
 |-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->

  <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

  <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->

  <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>

  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
    <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->

    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
  </servers>

  <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
   |
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
   | it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred
   | server for that repository.
   |-->
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>

  <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is
   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a
   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
   |       variables for plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->
  <profiles>
    <!-- profile
     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
     | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
     | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
     |
     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
     | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
     | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
     | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
     |
     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->

    <!--
     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
     | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
     | might hypothetically look like:
     |
     | ...
     | <plugin>
     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
     |
     |   <configuration>
     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
     |   </configuration>
     | </plugin>
     | ...
     |
     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
     |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
     |
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    -->
  </profiles>

  <!-- activeProfiles
   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
   |
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  -->
</settings>
```

Comment: What I see is that you are trying to download **jrebel-maven-plugin** from [link](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases) and there is not directory named **zeroturnaround**. BTW the message _the trustAnchors 
parameter must be non-empty_ means you are missing some keystore or the keystore is in invalid format.

Comment: it's the first time I use maven. Could you tell me what to do? Thank you

Comment: Not sure. Try to change the repo to **https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/**. This one works. Post your pom.xml (from the project) and maven setting.xml (MAVEN_HOME/conf)

Comment: i use this code: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. My Linux version blocked the downloading maven's jar packages. I solved by the following certificates:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
sudo apt install ca-certificates-java --reinstall
```

Then, I followed the geonetwork installation instructions (https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/master/software_development) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should work:

- download jrebel-plugin from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zeroturnaround/jrebel-maven-plugin/1.1.5)
- go to **/home/your_user/.m2/repository** and copy the jar to **org/zeroturnaround/jrebel-maven-plugin/1.1.5** directory (must exist)

Try to compile again.

**EDIT**

Go to your local pom.xml and change the line 1185 from:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases

to

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public

Comment: In /home/your_user/.m2/repository the jar org / zeroturnaround / jrebel-maven-plugin / 1.1.5 is there. if I compile it will not work.

Comment: Is there with the name **jrebel-maven-plugin-1.1.5.jar** and size **21K**? Or may be a bit strange name, something like lastUpdated? Post the file you have on your machine in /MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml.

Comment: No, the name is "jrebel-maven-plugin-1.1.5.jar.lastUpdated", but in your link there isn't download.

Comment: How you do it download jrebel-plugin?
Your link is dependency of the pom.xml

Comment: The file jrebel-maven-plugin-1.1.5.jar.lastUpdated is incorrect. It has 1K size and is not a jar file. To download click on **maven-plugin** link, in the middle, on the right there is 21K. Past the file in your repository and compile again.

Comment: Your response work, but, now, i have new error:
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.6.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.6.1 from/to oss.sonatype.org-github-releases (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]

Comment: I load jar file maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1, but not work.

Can you help me?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Try to change to this repo and let we see if works.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. First at all reverse changes in pom.xml. You can download maven-clean-plugin from public maven repository but you'll get the same error for all dependencies. **Are you behind proxy?**

Comment: No, I don't have proxy. From eclipse, with your change, I don't have error, but when I run, to command line, "mvn package install -DskipTests" I have the error.

Comment: Probably you use differnet maven versions in eclipse and your sistem. If in eclipse works try to use the generated jar

Comment: I try from eclipse terminal to run the command and it not work. I have the first problem. Some idea?

Comment: What I understand is that you run maven build from eclipse and it works, but from command line it doesn't. The eclipse command line is like the shell, must take values from the shell environment. If you can compile from eclipse through "Run as..." that is because you use differnet versions of maven in IDE and system. Just use the eclipse build. The other way is to download all failing jars and put in .m2/repository. Cannot tell anything else, sorry.