# Maven build fails when building Geonetwork

Tags: java, maven, build

I am trying to build Geonetwork with Maven.
The source code is from here: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/3.10.x

I follow this tutorial to build Geonetwork: https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/tutorials/introduction/deployment/build.html

But when I build it, these errors appear:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project common: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/GeonetHttpRequestFactory.java:[59,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class PreDestroy
[ERROR]   location: package javax.annotation
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/Xml.java:[70,22] package javax.xml.bind does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/Xml.java:[71,22] package javax.xml.bind does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/GeonetHttpRequestFactory.java:[72,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class PreDestroy
[ERROR]   location: class org.fao.geonet.utils.GeonetHttpRequestFactory
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/Xml.java:[376,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JAXBContext
[ERROR]   location: class org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/Xml.java:[376,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable JAXBContext
[ERROR]   location: class org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mn/Downloads/core_geonetwork/core-geonetwork-3.10.x/common/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/utils/Xml.java:[377,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Unmarshaller
[ERROR]   location: class org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :common
```

So there seems to be something with the package javax.annotation. I tried this hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63268748/5621619 but it does not help. I also tried to replace the plugin repository according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53853896/5621619 but it does not help.

My Java version is as follows:

```
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My Maven version is as follows:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\opt\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 15.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
Default locale: de_CH, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

How can I get this build process to run?

Answer (score 1):

This release of GeoNetwork requires the use of Java 8, that's why you are getting a compile error. You need to install Java 8 and then configure the JAVA_HOME to Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed Jaafar is correct, as Java 8 is required when building Geonetwork following instructions from https://geonetwork-opensource.org/downloads.html. I ran into the same problem and was able to resolve by executing

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Ref: [What is the installation path of AdoptOpenJDK 8.232 in appVeyor in the macos image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656165/what-is-the-installation-path-of-adoptopenjdk-8-232-in-appveyor-in-the-macos-ima)

And if you don't yet have Java 8, brew makes installation easy and only requires you run

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

Ref: [How to install Java 8 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac)